# Validate coordinates in DMS format in a Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to validate a textbox which is taking coordinates in Degree Minutes and Seconds or Degree and Minutes or in Degrees format divided by a space between them.

Comment: If you don't get any answers here, you may try to generalize your question and ask on [SO]. By generalize, I mean you should ask about the actual format (ie. 3 2-digit numbers separated by spaces) rather than the type of data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What code have you tried so far? And can we assume you know that 1 degree = 60 minutes and 1 minute = 60 seconds?

Comment: See this online converter http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html It'd D M S are in separate boxes, but it may help you a lot.